# Joining strings and replacing space with character

Tags: python

I have this following code:

```
from itertools import permutations
a = list(itertools.permutations(['test', 'text', 'new']))
```

This produces:

```
[('test', 'text', 'new'),
 ('test', 'new', 'text'),
 ('text', 'test', 'new'),
 ('text', 'new', 'test'),
 ('new', 'test', 'text'),
 ('new', 'text', 'test')]
```

How can do it so that for every row the string is joined and the space between the words are replaced with &. Thus for example the first line in this above list would look like :

```
test & text & new
```

Comment: list(map(lambda x: ' & '.join(x), a))

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strings = [" & ".join(x) for x in a]
```

Output:

```
>>> for s in strings: print(s)

test & text & new
test & new & text
text & test & new
text & new & test
new & test & text
new & text & test
>>>
```

Comment: What do you mean by why you are not able to do that? Do you face any error? and did you put "the list" as string inside join function? Join function will always take a list as input

Comment: Here is what i did, `s = "&"' `and `s.join(a)` and i get `' TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found'` !

Comment: @newcoder use `[" & " .join(x[0]) for x in a]`

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but for py >= 3.6 you can also use:

```
from itertools import permutations

a = [f"{x[0]} & {x[1]} & {x[2]}" for x in permutations(['test', 'text', 'new'])]
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/8f1bf09a79)